# How can I put my Excel template on Excel templates store

Tags: excel, office365, excel-2010, ms-office, export-to-excel

I have an Excel file that I made with a lot of validations and formulas that I want to share for all of my website users to input their own data. I think the best thing that I can do is to make my Excel file into a template and make it available on the Excel template store https://templates.office.com/en-us/templates-for-excel

However, after a lot of research I am not sure how to do that. Does anyone know how I can publish an Excel template to the Excel template store: https://templates.office.com/en-us/templates-for-excel

Comment: I think this question is out of scope because it's not about programming or software development. Maybe you could ask on Microsoft forums or Superuser

Comment: A download from your website seems the most obvious possibility. Why would Microsoft let you post your unchecked stuff on their site?